# File path for spec/runner/formatter/html_formatter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am using `"require 'spec/runner/formatter/html_formatter'"` in one of my ruby files and I am getting the error as:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- spec/runner/formatter/html_formatter (LoadError)
```

I am a noob in ruby and cannot see any ruby related folders in my home folder. (I am using a mac).

Please let me know how do I look into this issue.

Comment: where are you running this file from?  Try to switch to the folder one up from spec and run the file.  If you are in /spec try cd .. then run your code

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you have rvm installed, if you're using rvm.

If rvm is installed in your home directory:

In terminal, `echo $HOME`
this will return your home directory.

`cd /whatever/returned` or `cd ~/.` will also change directory into your home directory

```
ls -a
```

will list all directories.

```
cd .rvm
cd gems
cd ruby-2.0.0-p195
cd gems
cd whatevergemname-version#
```

Find the file you are looking for inside of that gem and then `pwd` will display the current location.

It should look in your dependencies though, so maybe you have conflicts between ruby installations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you familiar with textmate installation in ubuntu?